# Getting negative predicted values after glm in R

Tags: r

i'm using a predict over glm in R. The dataset that i'm using is Smarket from the library ISLR:

```
test.glm <- glm(Direction ~ Year+Lag1+Lag2+Lag3+Lag4+Lag5+Volume,data=test,family=binomial())
test.glm.predict <- predict(test.glm,type="response")
```

But the values of test.glm.predict are values negatives and idk why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems to be fishy with your statement of negative values. I get all positive values as shown with summary. Please consider clearing your global environment, i.e., rm(list=ls()) and then re-try

```
> test<-ISLR::Smarket
> test.glm <- glm(Direction ~ Year+Lag1+Lag2+Lag3+Lag4+Lag5+Volume,data=test,family=binomial())

> test.glm.predict <- predict(test.glm,type="response")
> summary(test.glm.predict)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.3527  0.4855  0.5245  0.5184  0.5550  0.6072
```